# How to change slider position in Makie animation?

Tags: animation, julia, slider, makie.jl

I want to create gif animation on my topoplot and I almost succeeded. The only problem is that slider position does not move. How to make it moving?

[image: see - slider position is unchanged]

Here is my code:

```
xs = range(-0.3, length=size(dat_e, 2), step=1 ./ 128) 
sg = SliderGrid(f[2, 1],
    (label="time", range=xs, format = "{:.3f} ms", startvalue = 0),
)
time = sg.sliders[1].value
str = lift(t -> "[$(round(t, digits = 3)) ms]", time)
topo_slice = lift((t, data) -> mean(data[1:30, indexin(t, xs), :], dims=2)[:,1], time, dat_e)
topo_axis = Axis(f[1, 1], aspect = DataAspect(), title = "Interactive topoplot")
topo = eeg_topoplot!(topo_axis, topo_slice, # averaging all trial of 30 participants on Xth msec
    raw.ch_names[1:30]; 
    positions=pos, # produced  automatically from ch_names
    #interpolation=DelaunayMesh(),
    enlarge=1,
    extrapolation=GeomExtrapolation(enlarge=1.0, geometry=Circle),
    label_text=true) # aspect ratio, correlation of height and width

text!(topo_axis, 1, 1, text = str,  align = (:center, :center))
xlims!(-0.2, 1.2)
ylims!(-0.2, 1.2)
hidedecorations!(topo_axis)
hidespines!(topo_axis) 

framerate = 1
timestamps = [-0.3, 0.0828125, 0.1609375, 0.2390625]

record(f, "animations/time_animation.gif", timestamps;
        framerate = framerate) do z
    sg.sliders[1].value[] = z
    time[] = z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will do the trick:

```
Makie.set_close_to!(sg.sliders[1], z)
```

(use this to set the value to `z`)